# Android ContentResolver.insert crashes with "unable to create new file"

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-contentresolver

I have a code inside some function of my activity:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "1354213408296.jpg");
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
Uri imageUri = contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, cv);

Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);

startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 712984419/*Some request code*/);
```

It crashes with:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create new file:
/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/1354213408296.jpg at
android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1335) at
android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:182) at
android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:136) at
android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:415) at
android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:730)
```

crashes on:

```
contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, cv);
```

The `"1354213408296.jpg"` is just `System.currentTimeInMillis() + ".jpg"`, so it is always unique

The `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is provided in manifest

Here is some phone's environment specifications (I am using ACRA to get it):

```
getDataDirectory=/data
getDownloadCacheDirectory=/cache
getExternalStorageAndroidDataDir=/mnt/sdcard/Android/data
getExternalStorageDirectory=/mnt/sdcard 
getExternalStorageState=removed
getRootDirectory=/system 
getSecureDataDirectory=/data 
getSystemSecureDirectory=/data/system 
is4GConfig=true 
is8GConfig=false 
isEncryptedFilesystemEnabled=false 
isExternalStorageEmulated=false 
isExternalStorageRemovable=true
```

What can I do to prevent this crashes?

Comment: Please tell me you found a workaround...

Comment: @n1k1ch - did u fix this ?

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tat Ratatouille, as I can remember, there was some hardware issue (probably sdcard was absent). Issue wasn't reproduced for a long time.

Comment: oh okay. I tried creating an emulator without an sdcard but m nt able to produce the crash unfortunately .. :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do. All you *seem* to be doing is trying to create a new row in MediaStore.Images.Media, with only a TITLE column. Putting in a title without the data to go with it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Edited - i have added some code. I want to do this: prepare Uri and save it; start camera activity and take photo; be able to access token photo by saved uri

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be just another exception you will get when no sdcard is present (I was able to reproduce it only on very weird emulators, but who knows?). Cases of missing sdcard should be handled for sure. My current solution is as follows:

```
public static Uri getImageFileUri(Context context) throws IOException{
    String fullFileName = generateImageFileName(imageName); // a method i have defined
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fullFileName);
        return context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
    } else {
        return Uri.fromFile(new File(fullFileName));
    }
}
```

This is the method I use to generate the `Uri` I will start the camera intent with. Afterwards I use it exactly like you do. The thing is that the value I return in the no sdcard case will not work properly, but on the other hand Android devices do not allow taking pictures if no sdcard is present. Using this solution you will succeed in taking picture if there is a sdcard and will launch the native camera that will show message "Insert sdcard in order to take picture" in the other cases.

Comment: i face this issue,but i dont know which emulator will actually cause this. will u please share how i cud create such an emulator or  may be if i cud get an emulator from genymotion ?

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille Maybe just create an emulator without any sdcard? Seeing the time I posted the answer aim for Nexus S without sdcard.

Comment: I did, but then i get a filenotfound exception but never an illegalstateexception, however, this does happen on real devices :( .. i want to replicate this in order to fix an issue